# Xdebug in VScode is not working by 'artisan serve' in MacOs

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a Laravel project in my MacOs but it's not working (Laravel + VScode + Xdebug).

phpinfo

[phpinfo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPmgI.png)

[phpinfo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VH9R.png)

php.ini

```
;zend_extension="xdebug.so"
[PHP]
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port = 8000 
xdebug.scream=0
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8000,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 8000
        }
    ]
}
```

VScode editor
[VScode editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8n3R.png)

Debug console of VScode

```
connection closed
connection closed
```

After run ***php artisan serve*** on terminal of VScode. The laravel project was running but the Xdebug was not trigged as i expected.
I don't know what is the problem. I've spent for several time but still could not be solved. Anyone who had experienced with VScode + Xdebug please help me.

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: What version of MacOS are you running ? 
Does the debugger doesn't start at all, or doesn't he halt at the breakpoints ?

Comment: Why are you assigning Xdebug port the same value as your web server? Please read the manual of how Xdebug works. It's Xdebug that connects to VSCode and NOT other way around. But even if it would ... webserver is already uses that port so VSCode cannot listen there... https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication

Comment: @BAerts , i'm using MacOS 10.14.4,  yes, it doesn't.

Comment: @LazyOne , I don't understand your meaning. You mean that i should set the port of php.ini and launch.json differently?

Comment: Xdebug is the one that connects to VSCode. VSCode must be listening on a FREE port. If VSCode does not listen, then Xdebug is unable to connect. Check the images in my link there -- it explains how it works. You cannot use `8000` port for Xdebug as you have your web server running there...

Comment: It's working now. After i changed the Port of 'launch.json' to 9000 and updated the 'php.ini' to " [xdebug] xdebug.remote_enable=1 xdebug.remote_autostart=1 " removed all old content. Finally, run the command "sudo apachectl restart" . Now i can debug my laravel project. Thank you @LazyOne for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. After i changed the Port of 'launch.json' to 9000 and updated the 'php.ini' to " [xdebug] xdebug.remote_enable=1 xdebug.remote_autostart=1 " removed all old content. Finally, run the command "sudo apachectl restart" . Now i can debug my laravel project. Thank you @LazyOne for supporting